# Sort 3D array using sort indices of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D and a 3D numpy array. The 2d array `A` has shape `(N, 3)` and the 3d array `B` has shape `(N, 3, 3)`. I want to sort `A` along `axis=1` and then apply that same sorting to array `B` sorting along `axis=2`.

I know I can do

`sort_idxs = np.argsort(A, axis=1)`

but then I don't know how to apply `sort_idxs` in the way I need to array `B`. `sort_idxs` has a shape of `(N, 3)` like `A`. Somehow I need to map the first dimension of `sort_idxs` to the first dimension of `B`, map the second dimension of `sort_idxs` to the 3rd dimension of `B`, and ignore the second dimension of `B`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using

```
sort_idxs = np.argsort(A, axis=1)
B_sorted = np.take_along_axis(B, sort_idxs[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=2)
```

Comment: `B[np.arange(10)[:, None, None], np.arange(3)[None, :, None], sort_idxs[:, None]]` also is OK.